# How to measure the similarity between two text documents?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, text-mining, similarity, similar-documents

Assume, I have 100 text documents, and I want to cluster those documents.

The first step is the construct pairwise similarity matrix `100X100` for the documents

My question is:

what are common way to measure similarity between two documents?

Thanks,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/how-to-compute-the-similarity-between-two-text-documents This has been answered before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general,there are two ways for finding document-document similarity

### TF-IDF approach

1. Make a text corpus containing all words of documents . You have to use tokenisation and stop word removal . NLTK library provides all .
2. Convert the documents into tf-idf vectors .
3. Find the cosine-similarity between them or any new document for similarity measure.

You can use libraries like NLTK , Scikit learn ,Gensim for Tf-Idf implementation . Gensim provides many additional functionality . 
See :  https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring14/compsci290/assignments/lab02.html

### Word Embedding

Google's Doc2Vec ,which is available in Gensim library can be used for document similarity .Additonaly,teh Doc2Vec model itself can compute the similarity score ( no cosine or anything needed her ) . You just need the vectorise the docs by tokenizing ( use NLTK ) and make a Doc2vec model using gensim and fins similarity and many using Gensim inbuilt methods like model.n_similarity for similarity between two documents .

### Other

Additionally,since your aim is to cluster documents,you can try Topic Modelling using LDA ( Latent Dirichet Allocation) or LSI ( Latent Semantic Indexing )  .

Answer (score 2):

The most common way is to measure the similarity between two text documents is distance in a vector space. A [vector space model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) can be created by using word count, [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf), word embeddings, or document embeddings. Distance is most often measured by [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). Once all the documents are in the same vector space, the 100x100 matrix with cosine similarity can be calculated.

"[Introduction to Information Retrieval](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/)" book goes into greater detail.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably approach this by creating a set of features for each document, you could, for example, use a [Bag of words representation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#the-bag-of-words-representation) or [TF-IDF term weighting](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting). Following this, you can compute the closeness of these features through some distance metric and use this as a measure of the similarity.